# Postgresql subquery no function matches the given name and argument types

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have mysql query and running well, but when i change to postgresql my query have error.

```
SELECT 
    A.ID AS parentid,
    A.caption AS parent,
    A.link,
    b.ID,
    b.caption AS child,
    b.link,
IF((SELECT COUNT ( be_priviledge.ID ) FROM be_priviledge WHERE role_id = 1 AND parent_id = A.ID AND child_id = b.ID ) > 0,
        CONCAT ( '...' ),
    IF(to_number(SELECT COUNT( be_priviledge.ID ) 
            FROM
                be_priviledge
                JOIN be_menu_parent ON be_priviledge.parent_id = be_menu_parent.ID 
            WHERE
                role_id = 1 
                AND parent_id = A.ID 
                AND isparent = 'N' 
            ) > 0,
            CONCAT ( '...' ),
            CONCAT ( '...' ) 
        ) 
    ) AS cek 
FROM
    be_menu_parent
    AS A LEFT JOIN be_menu_child AS b ON A.ID = b.parent_id 
WHERE
    A.ismenu = 'Y' 
ORDER BY
    A.ID,
    b.ID ASC
```

the error is

> LINE 10:  IF((SELECT COUNT( be_priviledge.ID ) 
>           ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

i am new with postgresql, i search about this error but always on create function

Comment: You can't use an `IF` in SQL. You probably want a [CASE expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE). Also `to_number(SELECT COUNT(..)..` makes no sense. `count()` already returns a number, there is no need to try to convert it to a number again.

Comment: oke i'll try use case